# Taking 5th Edition D&D Spells into 4th Edition D&D

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, dnd-4e, house-rules, conversion

Okay, so this is a question I have been thinking of for awhile, and I really want to make it work. Want I'm thinking of is taking roleplay-oriented spells from 5th Edition D&D and putting them into 4th Edition. I'm talking charm person, light, Thaumaturgy, Disguise self, minor illusion, and spells like that. NO combat spells, only spells designed really for out of combat use (at least in 5th edition terms). I LOVE 4th Edition combat way more than 5th's, but sometimes the game feels limited due to lack of roleplay oriented spells. I realize that Wizard gets some spells like this, and Bard has fast friends, but those cover a very narrow portion of what you can do in 5th Edition.

I was thinking of making the "spell list" for each class separate from the powers each receives, and from there just using the 5th edition rules for how many spells and what spells you can have. Then it would simply be treated like a Power. Roll to hit vs a Defense, like Charm Person vs Will or Minor Illusion vs Passive Insight, stuff like that. Dunno if having spell slots would work, or something along those lines. Just wanna know any ideas you guys might have, or if this is even worth considering. But I can't be the only one who dreams of 5th Edition spells in 4th. Like the best of both worlds. Thanks for any responses, really appreciate it.

Comment: This is rather broad, and almost entirely opinion based. I don't think this site is a good fit for it. You can try in [chat] though, people might enjoy talking about it.

Comment: Alternatively, you could take this to a forum, [here's a list of them that we recommend](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/23064).